# get the class of the button inside the form that has been currently clicked

Tags: jquery

OK, I want to get the class of the current clicked button inside a form and i tried this and so i have this code but unfortunately, it doesnt work and instead, a alertbox popup with the "undefine" text. it should be, an alertbox will popup with the class of the current clicked button.

```
$('#aholder form').submit(function(){
    var button = $(this).find("button").attr("class");
    alert(button);
    return false;
});
```

Hope someone could help and oh, I have several forms and i have those each buttons with a unique class on those each forms and i want to get the class of the current clicked button which inside of the form and so here's the html thing to be look for..

```
<div id="aholder">
    <form id="gs" action="processor.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="input" value="input1" />
        <button class="globalsettings">Global Settings</button>
    </form>
    <form id="pp" action="processor.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="input" value="input2" />
        <button class="Postapage">Post a page</button>
    </form>
    <form id="logoff" action="processor.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="input" value="input3" />
        <button class="Logout">Logout</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

PS: im open in any ideas, recommendations, suggestions and anything that can be added. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code works in an isolated test: http://jsfiddle.net/JRCNp/. Check your error console for other potential issues.

Comment: Yes, i see your code, its working on you but here, to me, it doesnt work. the alertbox said "undefine", i dont know whats going on but im still checking around on this stuff.

Comment: In what browser are you seeing the issue?

Comment: i use google chrome, but when i check your code at jsfiddle and run it and play along, its work just fine as i need.. but here in my local view it doesnt work, i run my code, but all i get is an alertbox saying "undefine" ..

Comment: Well... that means there's something different between the code you've posted here and the code you're running locally. Are you running a local server for testing?

Comment: yes, i run local server for testing and definitely I am currently still on a check on this stuff and trying to find out what is really going on.

Answer (score 0):

The example code seems to work for me aswell, but if you wan't the buttons class, why not bind the event to buttons :

```
$('button','#aholder form').on('click', function(e){
    var button = $(e.target).attr("class");
    alert(button);
    return false;
});​
```